# How do you generically change the colour of the text output within files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, colors

This is a specific question about controlling the simple text OUTPUT in files within VS Code.  For example, if you run a Jupyter Notebook file any text that is output below the cell.  Another example (since it seems to default to the same colour) is the text colour that is diplayed when opening a text file in VS Code.

Here is an example.  Note I am not talking about the already coloured syntax from the code, but rather the output text colour below the cell:

[image]

If you need further information, please let me know.  Thanks!

---

Update:

In the settings.json file it is possible to change the background color of the Jupyter Notebook output cell by entering this setting:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"notebook.cellEditorBackground": ""#ffffff"}
```

However, there does not appear to be a notebook. style setting for the foreground text.  I feel like this must be covered elsewhere in a more generic text setting.

Comment: show a simple image and mark the area you want to color

Comment: have added now, hope that is clearer

Comment: Now i got it, and apparently it's impossible. You can get the API reference for notebooks [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#notebook-colors). [This Github's issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8977) sounds related. Apparently, it uses terminal foreground, so changing your terminal's colors may help. (Not confirmed by me though)

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the solution that I found below and offered as an answer, but it is not specific enough, since it changes colours elsewhere in the editor also.  However, it does change the colour of the text as needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of settings to do this.

Basically, each valuable "word" in VSCode are intepreted as a token. Those tokens can be classified as part of a context that in many ways we developers already know, like: "keywords", "comments", "variables", etc. Each of those have a particular setting to define it's color. The fastest and easiest way to do this change is to try finding a marketplace theme (you can find [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace) using `@category:"themes"` on the search box).

With a chosen theme, or if you want to do it by yourself, you can start customizing your settings by your own way on your `settings.json` file. You can reach it by pressing `CTRL + P` and writting `>settings`.

Here is an example configuration of customizing color for a specific theme:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
        "comments": "#229977"
    },
    "[*Dark*]": {
        "variables": "#229977"
    },
    "[Abyss][Red]": {
        "keywords": "#f00"
    }
}
```

And here is an example of "do it by yourself" using `.tmTheme` file.

```
{
  "type": "dark",
  "colors": {
    "editor.background": "#1e1e1e",
    "editor.foreground": "#d4d4d4",
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#404040",
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#333333",
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#007acc",
    "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#bbbbbb"
  },
  "tokenColors": "./Diner.tmTheme"
}
```

> Note: Those examples were taken from the VSCode docs. It explains this in detail. You can find it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) and if you look to do it your own, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme)

Also, themes aren't limitted to the tokens. You can change almost any colors in your VSCode.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already indeed familiar with this process.  I am struggling to find where the setting is for editing the specific text that I asked about.  It is much harder given the fact that the Developer: Inpsect Editor Tokens and Scopes method is not available for the text that I mention.

Comment: I think that @riov8's answer is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: It is not, but perhaps there was some abiguity in my original question, so I have updated accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: It could have been any non-error cell output, not one that was the result of a print function.  This was just deployed for the purpose of an example.

Answer (score 0):

You use ANSI Color Escape codes

This will print the word `Example` in blue

```
print('An \x1b[34mExample\x1b[0m')
print('An \x1b[94mExample\x1b[0m')
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting that can be edited in the settings.json file is:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"editor.foreground": "#ffffff"}
```

This is the solution that I was looking for and finally found, so just updating.  Thanks!

As a side note, I am suprised that there does not appear to be a specific Jupyter Notebook output cell foreground colour setting (or indeed a generic output foreground colour setting at least that I have found).  Thanks!